# Cookies work in safari, but not in chrome or mozilla using nginx on localhost

Tags: node.js, nginx, cookies, proxy, reverse-proxy

I just switched from using node as my reverse proxy to nginx and it broke my cookie authentication i.e. user does not get logged in on mozilla and chrome, but still works fine on safari. Could somebody help me figure this out please?

This is my nginx reverse proxy setup:

```
server {
   listen       8080;
   server_name  localhost;

   location /api {
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
       proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3001;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding credentials: 'same-origin' to my fetch ajax requests